# Calculation of the Accuracy of a Keras Neural Network in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, finance

I have created a Keras neural network. The neural network was trained during eight epochs, and it outputs this loss value and accuracy:

```
Epoch 1/8
2009/2009 [==============================] - 0s 177us/step - loss: 0.0824 - acc: 4.9776e-04
Epoch 2/8
2009/2009 [==============================] - 0s 34us/step - loss: 0.0080 - acc: 4.9776e-04
Epoch 3/8
2009/2009 [==============================] - 0s 37us/step - loss: 0.0071 - acc: 4.9776e-04
Epoch 4/8
2009/2009 [==============================] - 0s 38us/step - loss: 0.0071 - acc: 4.9776e-04
Epoch 5/8
2009/2009 [==============================] - 0s 35us/step - loss: 0.0070 - acc: 4.9776e-04
Epoch 6/8
2009/2009 [==============================] - 0s 38us/step - loss: 0.0071 - acc: 4.9776e-04
Epoch 7/8
2009/2009 [==============================] - 0s 36us/step - loss: 0.0068 - acc: 4.9776e-04
Epoch 8/8
2009/2009 [==============================] - 0s 40us/step - loss: 0.0070 - acc: 4.9776e-04
```

Is there any way to find the variation percentage between the actual price and prediction for every single day in the data set?

Here is the neural network:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import numpy as np
#import quandle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import math
import pandas_datareader as web

def func_stock_prediction(stockdata, start, end):
  start = start
  end = end
  df = web.DataReader(stockdata, "yahoo", start, end)
  df = df[['Close']]


  previous = 5


  def create_dataset(df, previous):
      dataX, dataY = [], []
      for i in range(len(df)-previous-1):
          a = df[i:(i+previous), 0]
          dataX.append(a)
          dataY.append(df[i + previous, 0])
      return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

  scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
  df = scaler.fit_transform(df)


  train_size = math.ceil(len(df) * 0.5)

  train, val = df[0:train_size,:], df[train_size:len(df),:]

  X_train, Y_train = create_dataset(train, previous)


  print(X_train)
  print(Y_train)

  print(X_train.shape)
  print(Y_train.shape)

  X_val, Y_val = create_dataset(val, previous)

  X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
  X_val = np.reshape(X_val, (X_val.shape[0], 1, X_val.shape[1]))

  model = keras.models.Sequential() 
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (1, 5)))
  model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear'))
  model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', 
                optimizer='adam', 
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=8)

  train = model.predict(X_train)
  val = model.predict(X_val)

  train = scaler.inverse_transform(train)
  Y_train = scaler.inverse_transform([Y_train])
  val = scaler.inverse_transform(val)
  Y_val = scaler.inverse_transform([Y_val])
  predictions = val


  trainPlot = np.empty_like(df)
  trainPlot[:, :] = np.nan
  trainPlot[previous:len(train)+previous, :] = train
  valPlot = np.empty_like(df)
  valPlot[:, :] = np.nan
  valPlot[len(train)+(previous*2)+1:len(df)-1, :] = val
  inversetransform, =plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(df))
  train, =plt.plot(trainPlot)
  val, =plt.plot(valPlot)
  plt.xlabel('Number of Days')
  plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
  plt.title("Predicted vs. Actual Stock Price Per Day")
  plt.show()

func_stock_prediction("PLAY", 2010-1-1, 2020-1-1)
```

Thank you for your assistance concerning this particular matter.

Comment: Please rename all 'val's to test. Your variables are named poorly and hard to follow.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Why did you ask the same question two times? Please delete your other question, you can always edit your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you want to print out variation in percentage in prediction while "training" neural network. If so, do something like this:

logic I have used to compute percent deviance from true value is:

`percent_deviance = 100 * |true - predicted| / predicted`

```
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

def variation_percentage(y_pred,y_true):
    deviation = np.subtract(y_pred - y_true)
    scaled_deviance = np.divide(deviation,y_true) # element-wise divide
    percent_deviance = np.absolute(scaled_deviance) * 100
    return K.mean(percent_deviance) # returns mean percent of deviance from original value
```

Then on your `model.compile` change it to:

```
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', 
                optimizer='adam', 
                metrics=['accuracy', variation_percentage])
```

Regardless, I hope you get the logic.